# Calling parent method of inherited class from base class

Tags: php, inheritance

The following example does not work because when `parent` is called in class `A`, php looks for the parent class of class `A` but it doesn't exist. I would rather this line to call `Test()` in class `B`.

Is this possible?

(I know this seems like a stupid example but it has a practical application)

```
abstract class A {
    function CallParentTest()
    {
        return call_parent_method('Test');
    }
}

abstract class B extends A {
    function Test()
    {
        return 'test passed';
    }
}

class C extends B {
    function Test()
    {
        return $this->CallParentTest();
    }
}

$object = new C();
echo $object->Test();
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I changed the `parent` keyword to the made up method `call_parent_method` because I think that may have been confusing people. I know there is no way to do this using the keyword.

Just as David Harkness pointed out, I am trying to implement the Template Method pattern but instead of using two different method names, I'm using one. `B::Test()` will be the default method unless substituted with alternate functionality.

Comment: Is there a real need to redeclare Test function in class C? Because if you do not redeclare Test in C, it will do just what you ask for - call the Test from class B.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be set up this way. Like I said, it looks stupid but this is the dumbed down version.

Comment: You could achieve it by doing some serious backflips in every child class that overrides the parent method by grabbing the stacktrace to determine whether `A` is the caller or not. If it is, do your thing. If not, call the parent method. This will be far more complicated than just having two methods, though, and I recommend against it.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, can you expand on that? I know how to do a backtrace to get the method and class called, I just don't know how to call `B::Test()` without having `C::Test()` called. In the end, if I have one complicated method doing this work, it's a lot less complicated than having almost every method in every class duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection to bypass the natural calling order for overridden methods. In any context simply create a `ReflectionMethod` for the method you'd like to call and invoke it. You don't need to do this from the class itself, but you will need to call `setAccessible(true)` if the method isn't public.

```
class A {
    public function bypassOverride() {
        echo "Hi from A\n";
        $r = new ReflectionMethod('B', 'override');
        $r->invoke($this);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function override() {
        echo "Hi from B\n";
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function override() {
        echo "Hi from C\n";
        $this->bypassOverride();
    }
}

$c = new C;
$c->override();
```

The output from this is

```
Hi from C
Hi from A
Hi from B
```

You could make `bypassOverride()` more generic and move it to a helper class if you need to do this a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying now and it's an interesting approach but this again puts the call to the parent method in class C and will result in a considerable amount of duplicated code.

Comment: I found an easier solution using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

No.

It makes no sense to use the `parent` keyword except in child classes. It's only purpose is to be used by *child* classes to call methods that it as overridden. Think about multi-level parent calls where a child calls its parent's method of the same name and, in turn, that parent calls *its* parent's method of the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of how inheritance normally works, what I'm attempting to do is slightly outside of the norm. PHP has many dynamic ways of calling methods and such, I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

webbiedave is correct regarding `parent`, but it looks like you're trying to implement the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern where the abstract base class calls a method that subclasses are expected to implement. Here's an example that demonstrates a horrible way to handle errors in your applications.

```
abstract class ExceptionIgnorer {
    public function doIt() {
        try {
            $this->actuallyDoIt();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // ignore the problem and it might go away...
        }
    }

    public abstract function actuallyDoit();
}

class ErrorThrower extends ExceptionIgnorer {
    public function actuallyDoIt() {
        throw new RuntimeException("This will be ignored");
    }
}

$thrower = new ErrorThrower;
$thrower->doIt(); // no problem
```

Here `doIt()` is the template method as it defines the overall algorithm to follow.

Comment: Yes I am, I was trying to see if there was a way to accomplish this in PHP without having to have two different method names. I'm planning to implement the template method pattern in many many places throughout a large application so using the same name would make development much easier.